# google API (Geocoding) request returns wrong language

Tags: php, api, google-maps, geocoding

related to the doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro i am using this api request to figure out the full address data (especially lat/lon)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=30449+hannover&sensor=false&language=en&key=YOURAPIKEY

the language parameter is the important part. its EN for english.

lets now face the result: "Niedersachsen" this part is german.

okay.. what a pitty.. i thought that google possibly doesnt know the english name of it so it returns the default german name since my request is about a german town but then i changed the api request a little bit and removed the ZIP (30449) of the address.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=hannover&sensor=false&language=en&key=YOURAPIKEY

now my result was CORRECT: "Lower Saxony" in english.

so obviously google knows the name.

am I doing something wrong? do you have any ideas? i cant get this issue sorted...

please advise.

thanks!

p.s. its a little related to this I think: [Google Geocoding API returns wrong language in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049068/google-geocoding-api-returns-wrong-language-in-response) but not completely... I have also already opened a bug report on google side just in case...

Comment: Might be expected behavior as per localization policy of Geocoding API. Have a look at explanations in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54470790/5140781

Comment: @xomena, thanks, yeah this seems to be a very similar issue (if not event exactly the same). in my point of view I am not even changing the "fetch level". I always do the same request, just adjustung the address paramter. in the example you refer to, he is doing a complete different fetch which causes the difference. dont you think so too? and also I am not searching on "street-level" or am i? what decide on which level I am searching? maybe I didnt understood the whole thing yet...

Answer (score -1):

I'm having Geocoding issues as well, ever since the new "pay-as-you-go" API nonsense.  Installed new API key after activiating a new CC attached accnt with Google dev.  Fixed things for a moment, but seems like cache issues are keeping the geocoding, as well as front side UX with the map embed itself (markers don't show, limited/no functionality).  Wish I had an answer for you, but for now, just commiserating...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about the request returning the wrong language